# Unicode extraction

Tags: python, regex, unicode, beautifulsoup

I have written a code which extracts url's from a certain web page, the problem which I am facing is that it doesn't extract the urls same way which is there on the web page, I mean if the URL is in some french language, it doesn't extract it the way it is. How should I solve this problem?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for i in range(0,500):
    o=36*i
    r=requests.get('http://www.barneys.com/barneys-new-york/men?start='+str(o)+'&format=page-element&sz=36')
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    links=soup.find_all("a",{"class":"thumb-link"})
    for link in links:
        print link.get('href')
```

Comment: It would be better if you add some code you're working with to your question as it'd be easier to give a piece of advice then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URLs are [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). For example, in the HTML the URL may be

```
http://www.barneys.com/rick-owens-boucl%C3%A9-scarf-504025220.html
```

but in your browser the URL may be *displayed* as

```
http://www.barneys.com/rick-owens-bouclé-scarf-504025220.html
```

To decode percent-encoded URL, use `urllib.unquote` in Python2 or `urllib.parse.unquote` in Python3:

```
>>> print(urllib.unquote('http://www.barneys.com/rick-owens-boucl%C3%A9-scarf-504025220.html'))
http://www.barneys.com/rick-owens-bouclé-scarf-504025220.html
```

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
try:
    # Python2
    from urllib import unquote
except ImportError:
    # Python3
    from urllib.parse import unquote

for i in range(0,500):
    o=36*i
    r=requests.get('http://www.barneys.com/barneys-new-york/men?start='+str(o)+'&format=page-element&sz=36')
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    links=soup.find_all("a",{"class":"thumb-link"})
    for link in links:
        print(unquote(link.get('href')))
```

---

In Python3 `link.get` returns a unicode `str`.
In Python2, `link.get` returns a `str` of bytes, which can be decoded with `utf-8` to obtain unicode:

```
print(unquote(link.get('href')).decode('utf-8'))
```